# managing CSS in master page, content page and user control?

Tags: asp.net, .net, css

In a web I am using content pages, master pages and user controls. Kindly guide me what are best practices to write css for all of these. Should in page ? In seprate file. A seprate file for each (content, master and user control) ? or one seprate file for all ?

What is the way to write in professional environments considering easy changes and extendability.

I am writing nesting CSS code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be dogmatic about stuff like this. As a rule of thumb put your styles that are used throughout your site in a separate stylesheet.

If you have a one-off style that only applies to one page or control, don't feel bad about just sticking it on the page itself. The more you do this though, the harder it is to modify the look of your whole site. There are trade-offs.

Comment: I agree in general that being "dogmatic" about ideals is often counter-productive. But this one is just so easy to do. The extra alt-tab cost to switch documents will always be saved when you later have to understand your css, imho.

Comment: seth, should I call css file in in user control or only in page ? Also in content page and master page both or only in content pages.

Comment: @haansi Link to the file wherever the styles are used. It doesn't matter if it's a master page, content page or user control.

Comment: @seth it does matter if he uses certain Javascript functionality.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Sure - there are many exceptions. I'm just answering as a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 2):

You should write separate css files, linked from the master page. How many files depends on the complexity of your app.

Putting css directly in your pages will cause unneeded extra bandwidth usage, whereas separate files could be cached. Same with Javascript, btw.

Comment: Andrew, should I call css file in in user control or only in page ? Also in content page and master page both or only in content pages.

Comment: Generally, you should link css files in the head,, before any javascript libraries. If you ever do any manipulation of styles via script, it's best to have them loaded before encountering javascript.